# Mapping of 2 attributes

Tags: java, hashmap, mapping

I have a list of 2 attributes, namely, entities and applications. Several entities can be a part of one application. Now, I want to map all entities with the same application to one application list. For this I have declared `HashMap <String, List <String>>`

While iterating over the list of the entities I wish to add them one by one to the list of the applications. 
In c++ I could have used a map wherein m[appName] would give the link list header and using that I could add to the existing list. Here in hashmap I need to put in (key, value) pair but how do I add to the existing list of the entities for an application?

Comment: Please share how you are doing it currently. Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Right now I am iterating multiple times, picking up an appName and then in that iteration I am adding all entities with this appName to a list. Finally at the end of the iteration I am adding this created list into the HashMap. But this is redundant since I am running the loop n^2 times.

Comment: I need something like m[appName] which will enable me to add that entity to an existing list of entities with the same appName or create a new list with that entity under that appName. This will enable me to run the loop just n times wherein I can just write: m[appName].add(current_entity_name)

Comment: Please share a simple data structure of entities and applications.

Comment: I have a list of DBObjects for the entities and applications where the DBObject contains the entity id and appName as the second attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding it would be like that

```
public class MapAdder {
    private Map<String, Set<String>> app2entryMap = new HashMap<>();

    ...

    public boolean addMapping(final String app, final String entry) {
        Set<String> entries = app2entryMap.get(app);

        if (entries == null) {
            entries = new HashSet<String>();
            app2entryMap.put(app, entries);
        }

        return entries.add(entry);
    }
}
```

Note that I've used `Set` instead of `List` to enforce uniqueness of entries within an app. If it'not your case/you don't need it - `List` is fine and might work faster.

Also note that there should be a correct `hashCode()`/`equals()` implementation for the real objects placed into `HashSet`, etc. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I used the get method of the Hashmap for my purpose. I used it like this :

```
m.get(key).add(value)
```

where in the 'key' is nothing but the appName and value is the entity id. Only thing to take care of is that for the first insertion I had to do a null check and if I found that 'get' returned null, I created a List of my own and inserted it.